# What's the difference between String and String[]?

Tags: java, string

Could anyone help me understand the difference? I need to understand for my class and they seem the same to me.

`String` or `String[]`

Comment: `String[]` is an array of Strings. `String` is a `String` object. Check this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Learn about these topics, `Array in Java` and `String in Java`. There are ample resources available on Internet. I am sure you can figure out by your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> String is -> a series of characters in your code that is enclosed in double quotes.

More details a bout [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)

> String[] -> An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a Strings.

More about [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `String` and `String[]` is that `String` is used to declare a single instance of a `String` object:

```
String name = "Cupcake";
```

On the other hand, `String[]` is used to declare an array of multiple strings:

```
String[] names = new String[] { "Joe", "Alice" };
```

In Java generally, arrays of type `<Type>` are declared using the following syntax:

```
<Type>[] types;
```

From the [official Java documentation for arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html):

> An array's type is written as `type[]`, where `type` is the data type of the contained elements; the brackets are special symbols indicating that this variable holds an array.

Answer (score 2):

`String` is used to create a single object of type `String`

`String[]` is an `Array`, containing a specified number of String objects.

Answer (score 1):

String is a class, and `String a` represents an object of this class (the String class represents an object containing a sequence of characters). While `String a[]` represents an **array** of objects of this type.
 An array is a kind of container. It can contain various objects inside. In this case with `String[]` you are specifying that this container has only `String` objects

```
     String a = "abc";   /*this is a String, notice it references only to one
     object, which is a sequence of characters*/

        String b[] = new String[]{"abc", "def"};  /*this is a String array. 
    It is instantiated with 2 String objects, and it cannot 
contain anything else other than String or its sub classes (i.e: no Integers or neither Object). */
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to array, String[] is used to store more than one string at a time.

Following is a sample program for String[]

```
public class JavaStringArrayExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // declare a string array with initial size
        String[] schoolbag = new String[4];

        // add elements to the array
        schoolbag[0] = "Books";
        schoolbag[1] = "Pens";
        schoolbag[2] = "Pencils";
        schoolbag[3] = "Notebooks";

        // this will cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        // schoolbag[4] = "Notebooks";

        // declare a string array with no initial size
        // String[] schoolbag;

        // declare string array and initialize with values in one step
        String[] schoolbag2 = { "Books", "Pens", "Pencils", "Notebooks" }    
        // print the third element of the string array
        System.out.println("The third element is: " + schoolbag2[2]);

        // iterate all the elements of the array
        int size = schoolbag2.length;
        System.out.println("The size of array is: " + size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.println("Index[" + i + "] = " + schoolbag2[i]);
        }

        // iteration provided by Java 5 or later
        for (String str : schoolbag2) {         
                 System.out.println(str);
        }

    }

}
```

Hope this will give you an idea.